# How to hide the loading icon during the closing of TreeView items using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

```js
    $.fn.extend({
        treed: function (o) {

          var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
          var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

          if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
            if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
            openedClass = o.openedClass;
            }
            if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
            closedClass = o.closedClass;
            }
          };

            //initialize each of the top levels
            var tree = $(this);
            tree.addClass("tree");
            tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
                var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
                branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
                branch.addClass('branch');
                branch.on('click', function (e) {
                    if (this == e.target) {
                        var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                        icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass);
                        $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>");         
                          setTimeout(()=>{
                            $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                            $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                          }, 400)
                    }
                })
                branch.children().children().toggle();
            });
            //fire event from the dynamically added icon
          tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('li').click();
            });
          });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
            //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
            tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
                $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                    $(this).closest('li').click();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    //Initialization of treeviews

    $('#tree1').treed();
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
              });
          });
      }
    });
    
    //Initialization of treeviews
    
    $('#tree1').treed();
    
    $('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

```css
.tree, .tree ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.tree ul {
  margin-left:1em;
  position:relative
}
.tree ul ul {
  margin-left:.5em
}
.tree ul:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border-left:1px solid
}
.tree li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 1em;
  line-height:2em;
  color:#369;
  font-weight:700;
  position:relative;
}
.tree ul li:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:10px;
  height:0;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin-top:-1px;
  position:absolute;
  top:1em;
  left:0
}
.tree ul li:last-child:before {
  background:#fff;
  height:auto;
  top:1em;
  bottom:0
}
.indicator {
  margin-right:5px;
}
.tree li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
}
.tree li button, .tree li button:active, .tree li button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#369;
  border:none;
  background:transparent;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  outline: 0;
}

.loading {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <ul id="tree2">
          <li>
             <a href="#">TECH</a>
             <ul>
                <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                <li>
                   Employees
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                         Reports
                         <ul>
                            <li>Report1</li>
                            <li>Report2</li>
                            <li>Report3</li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Human Resources</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
             XRP
             <ul>
                <li>Company Maintenance</li>
                <li>
                   Employees
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                         Reports
                         <ul>
                            <li>Report1</li>
                            <li>Report2</li>
                            <li>Report3</li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>Employee Maint.</li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Human Resources</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I have a TreeView and I have implemented a loading icon to show while expanding the TreeView items (ul/li).
The requirement is to only show the loading icon while expanding the TreeView items and not show it during the close of the TreeView items.
The animated icon is working well, but unfortunately it also appears when closing TreeView items. The animated loading icon should not be displayed when closing TreeView items. I am open to any help from experts here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a flag variable and toggle it for every parent click.

```
$.fn.extend({
  treed: function (o) {

    var openedClass = 'fa-minus-circle';
    var closedClass = 'fa-plus-circle';

    if (typeof o != 'undefined'){
      if (typeof o.openedClass != 'undefined'){
      openedClass = o.openedClass;
      }
      if (typeof o.closedClass != 'undefined'){
      closedClass = o.closedClass;
      }
    };

//initialize each of the top levels
      var tree = $(this);
      tree.addClass("tree");
      tree.find('li').has("ul").each(function () {
          var branch = $(this); //li with children ul
          branch.prepend("<i class='indicator fas " + closedClass + "'></i>");
          branch.addClass('branch');

          // declare a flag to toggle
          let flag = false;
          branch.on('click', function (e) {
              if (this == e.target) {
                  // toggle on click
                  flag = !flag;
                  var icon = $(this).children('i:first');
                  icon.toggleClass(openedClass + " " + closedClass); 

                  // show loader only when its opened, and collpase once toggled   
                  if(flag) {
                    $(this).append("<div class='loading'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'</span></div>"); 
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      $(this).find('.loading').remove();
                      $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                    }, 400)
                  } else {
                    $(this).children().children().slideToggle(400);
                  }
              }
          })
          branch.children().children().toggle();
      });

//fire event from the dynamically added icon
    tree.find('.branch .indicator').each(function(){
      $(this).on('click', function () {
          $(this).closest('li').click();
      });
    });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains an anchor instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>a').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
      //fire event to open branch if the li contains a button instead of text
      tree.find('.branch>button').each(function () {
          $(this).on('click', function (e) {
              $(this).closest('li').click();
              e.preventDefault();
          });
      });
  }
});

//Initialization of treeviews

$('#tree1').treed();

$('#tree2').treed({openedClass:'fa-folder-open', closedClass:'fa-folder'});
```

Make sure to declare this variable inside the child iterator only to create a separate variable for each child. If you declare outside, it wont work.

Comment: unfortunately its not work, you can edit on snippet and post your full Answer.

Comment: It was the part where modification was required, I have added the complete code now(js code, not html and css).

Comment: I replaced your JavaScript code with my old code, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Strange, it works for me, here is the code link https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-yz52ms?file=index.js